# Merge two versions of the same database: duplicate id errors

Tags: mysql, database, merge, foreign-key-relationship

I am trying to merge two databases together. The two are basically the same database but with different data.

I deleted 90% of the records in the database(V1). Then I inserted new records(V2).

Now for an unfortunate reason I need all the old records I deleted as well as to keep the new records, but I get a `#1062 - Duplicate entry 'x' for key 'PRIMARY'` error.

Basically there are tables like `brands`, `colors`, `categories` etc.. that are structured like this `(id, name, slug)` and then there are tables that have foreign keys that reference those tables. Of course there are also other tables with relationships, but this is basically the pattern.

Is there any way I can merge the two versions where I only insert the records from V1 that are not already in V2 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could dump your V1 database and change all  the `INSERT` statements to  `INSERT IGNORE` . Beware of the order of insertions to not have foreign key errors